# Is it possible to access Tasklet from JobExecutionContext of spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to cancel execution of a tasklet without cancelling to entire step/job. I have implemented the tasklet in such a way that it can be cancelled based on a flag. But JobExecutionContext  does not provide any medium to access the tasklet? Is there any way to access the tasklet instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
We can access an executing tasklet from jobRegistry 

    JobExecution jobExecution = findExecutionById(executionId);
try {
Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName());
if (job instanceof StepLocator) {
// can only process as StepLocator is the only way to get the step object
                    // get the current stepExecution
for (StepExecution stepExecution : jobExecution.getStepExecutions()) {
if (stepExecution.getStatus().isRunning()) {
try {
 // have the step execution that's running -> need to 'stop' it
 Step step = ((StepLocator) job).getStep(stepExecution.getStepName());
 if (step instanceof TaskletStep) {

                        //Implement your logic here         }
                                }
                            } catch (NoSuchStepException e) {
                                logger.warn("Step not found", e);
                                throw new WorkflowServiceException("Step not found", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (NoSuchJobException e) {
                logger.warn("Cannot find Job object in the job registry. StoppableTasklet#stop() will not be called", e);
                throw new WorkflowServiceException(
                        "Cannot find Job object in the job registry. StoppableTasklet#stop() will not be called", e);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is possible with decider

```
    public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {


    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {

        if (condition) {
        // choose what ever you want to do 
        return new FlowExecutionStatus("");    

            }
        // choose what ever you want to do 
        return new FlowExecutionStatus("");
    }
}
```

for example you can check here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html

Comment: I am looking for instance from JobExecution context. It will not be a singleton bean. There will be more than one instance of same tasklet with different implementation.

Comment: @MacleanPinto You don't need the JobExecution for that. Use a decider to check that the tasklet was stopped and make the flow continue to the next step.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine My requirement is to cancel the tasklet at run time. I have to trigger the cancel. As of now Spring batch allows cancellation at step level.

Comment: @Maclean Pinto you can put the tasklet inside a separate step , and then you can skip that step - but i would still suggest you to check out the decider once

Comment: Everything we talk about here happens at runtime. You cancel the tasklet step at runtime and then the decider checks the status at runtime and decides to go to the next step or not. I see no need for `JobExecution` for this use case.